# Get a list of all the url calls going out from your ip address

Tags: linux, url, command-line, tcp, fedora

I use a fedora operating system and I am running a recursive function which makes a call to a rest api. It makes around 5000 calls, and it does take a while to execute the whole script. So just as a double check I wanted to see if I really can get a list of all the urls that my computer is hitting.

Something similar to top or ps aux command that lists all the urls that are being currently hit and any information of how much memory are they using etc.

I am kind of a linux novice, so I am trying to get around the command line to learn more.

Comment: "getting a list of all the URL calls" doesn't make any sense. Are you trying to monitor a particular program like Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: umm no, I trying to monitor a process, when I try to look at the access log, I only see one "get" request hitting my apache, but that url would hit a rest api many times, recursively, so I am trying to figure out if it is hitting the rest api url or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution :

- tcpdump
- wireshark
- Proxy (Fiddler)

I think the easiest way is using wireshark.

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263116/wireshark-vs-firebug-vs-fiddler-pros-and-cons) from SO

Comment: You can find a lot of information on the web about those possibilities. For me, i'm doing this : http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/AppToolstcpdump.html