# $.ajax URL inquiry

Tags: javascript, ajax

Will toDistance.php ran after calling this function? It seems like toDistance.php is not called. Thanks

```
function myAjax(volunteerDist, jid){
            $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'toDistance.php',
            data : ({
                distance:volunteerDist,
                id:jid
            }),
            success: function(){
                 alert('worked');
            },
               error :function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
           complete : function(){
               alert('thanks');
           }
        });
```

Comment: @JoeTuskan in my toDistance.php, I had an echo, but it did not do so, how come?

Comment: Because it's ajax. not a page refresh.

Comment: @JoeTuskan okay, now, volunteerDist and jid are arrays, how can I $_GET it in my toDistance.php?

Comment: You need to make more "home-work" before posting a question. **What do you see in firebug?** stackoverflow isn't a "charades game" kind of place

Comment: i am sorry.. i do not know firebug.. it just knew about this today and read about this $_GET

Comment: SO, if you already know firebug, fiddler, etc. what do you see in there? See this ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263116/wireshark-vs-firebug-vs-fiddler-pros-and-cons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried out by taking arguments on your success function? Try this code.

```
function myAjax(volunteerDist, jid){
            $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'toDistance.php',
            success: function( data ){
            ///CHECK UR UPCOMING DATA
                 alert(data.jid);
                 alert('worked');
            },
               error :function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
           complete : function(){
               alert('thanks');
           }
        });
```

Comment: it says undefined.. what does that mean?

Comment: does it ouput undefined before printing 'worked' ? Looks like your script isn't returning any data

Comment: okay, but how can that be? before I called myAjax(volunteerDist, jid); i printed their values and the results are there

Comment: @jose i alerted (volunteerDist) and it alerted all the values inside

Comment: try by alert the full object and see what is returns. Object or null alert.

Answer (score 0):

> Will toDistance.php ran after calling this function?

If the data parameter is what the server expecting to get, **Yes**.

Use `firebug`, check what is going on with your request and stop guessing...

Answer (score 0):

It seems OK. Try to track web traffic with [FIddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and check if the script is called and the arguments.

If you're debbuging with Safari, Chrome or Firefox you can record the traffic.
Check for POST variables, script location etc.