# Capturing Traffic of a program using Fiddler

Tags: .net, http, httpwebrequest, fiddler, sniffing

I tried to use a website's API, but I always become a ProtocolError (UnsafeHeaderParsing did not help me) so I decide to capture the traffic of a program which is using that API, so that I know which attributes I have to set in the Header/POST...The problem is that Fiddler is currently only capturing the traffic of my browsers, how can I change that so, that it captures traffic of programs which are runnung on my localhost.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about what program you're trying to capture. Fiddler can capture HTTP/HTTPS traffic from virtually everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Message Analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649776.aspx) can do a great deal of capture and analysis, correlating events and so on. You can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40308).

[NetMon](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) is the old alternative, now replaced by Message Analyzer.

An of course, [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) if you want a non-OS alternative.

Also read [Wireshark vs Firebug vs Fiddler - pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263116/wireshark-vs-firebug-vs-fiddler-pros-and-cons)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using ASP.Net (either MVCor Webforms) you need to set a proxy in your web application.
In order to do that, you need to change your web.config and set the defaultProxy setting to the Fiddler proxy:

> <configuration>
>    <system.net>
>     <defaultProxy>
>      <proxy bypassonlocal="false" usesystemdefault="true" />
>      </defaultProxy>
>    </system.net>
>   </configuration>

After changing the web.config, you'll see the request/responses made by your application in Fiddler.

See ref: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp

Comment: I want to capture the traffic of an extern program, not a program made by me.